# Is running Windows 7 in VirtualBox on Ubuntu comparable to Windows 7 alone?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-7, virtualbox, wine

I like Ubuntu for its speed and security, but I play many Windows-only games that don't run very well (or at all) in WINE. I don't want to have a dual-boot setup either because it would be quite tiresome to constantly swap between Ubuntu and Windows 7. So, does Windows 7 running in VirtualBox on Ubuntu perform the same (mainly graphics-wise) or comparable to running Windows 7 alone? More specifically, would running a graphics-intense game like GTA IV on Windows 7 in VirtualBox on Ubuntu perform the same, or have the same framerate, as running GTA IV on Windows 7 alone? Also, is there any other way of emulating Windows 7 in Ubuntu that might work better (excluding WINE)? Thanks!

Comment: I think no other options available other Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox Gaming is in general not a good experience. You wont have the great 3D support that you desire and applications that require a lot of resources will lag. Some games will probably work, like minecraft and minesweeper. **Heavy games like GTA IV will not work**

Checkout [Gaming with Virtualbox, has it worked for you?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283964/gaming-with-virtualbox-has-it-worked-for-you)

Comment: Especially for older games, that don't need the latest 3d hardware support, VirtualBox gaming can work great. WinXP in a VirtualBox can run some of the latest online poker programs that don't have a Ubuntu/linux client and don't work with wine...

Answer (score 0):

It would perform very poorly. Unless you have a really powerful computer I would not even attempt it. Dual booting is the way to go. I would also highly recommend looking into an SSD just for Windows 7 so that you can reduce boot times as much as possible. In conclusion, VM is not the way to go if you want to play games your pc.
Hope it helps!
Matt